# Javascript number is NaN

Tags: javascript, undefined, nan

I've been looking around and I can't seem to find out why this is happening or how to fix it. I've been trying different things for about 2 days, now its time to ask for help before I rip the rest of my hair out (I'm new to Java)

I know the code is very long winded at the moment, but its like that for readability to see why its not working for me.

```
     function getBaB()
{   
      var BaB=0;
      var theForm = document.forms["prrform"];
      var basebab = theForm.elements["charbab"];
      BaB = basebab.value;
      return BaB;
}

 var armour_types = new Array();
```

//This is the bit that doesn't work

```
 armour_types["Heavy"] = (getBaB.value) ;
```

//It just returns undefined, and if I parseInt then I get NaN. I just can't see why it isn't defined.

```
 armour_types["Medium"] = 10;
 armour_types["Light"] = 2;
 armour_types["Adamantine"] = 10;
 armour_types["Mithral"] = 5;
 armour_types["Unarmoured"] = 0;


function calculateTotal()
{
   var TotalPRR = getArmourType();
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPRR');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total PRR "+TotalPRR;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPRR');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

I can post the HTML if needed.

Thanks in advance :

Comment: Are you actually calling `getBaB.value`, or have you just forgot the `()` in the example?

Comment: The `getBaB()` is already returning the value of the element of interest. So change your code to `armour_types["Heavy"] = getBaB();`

Comment: No i didn't forget the () in the example, I've been writing it wrong the entire time, but changing it still didn't work.

Comment: Place a breakpoint iside getBaB() and check the BaB value.it is undefined i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kirubhananth Chellam is correct with his answer:

```
armour_types["Heavy"] = getBaB();
```

But as you're new to Javascript (Java has a very different syntax) I'll try an explain where you're going abit wrong an see if I can help you further.

Javascript is loosely typed - and this is key to the entire language. Consider...

```
var x = 0;
```

... as you imagine assigns value 0 to x. Simple but a key starting point as the assignment...

```
x = "hello"
```

... is not so simple to understand. In strongly typed languages, this would return a type error however is Javasript, this is perfectly acceptable. As is...

```
x = function(){
    var y = 0;
    return y;
}
```

...even after x has been assigned a numeric value.

The reason this is important as when Javascript is interpreted at runtime, function declarations such as...

```
function x(){
    ...
}
```

... are actually interpreted in the same way as variable assignments...ie....

```
var x = function(){
    ...
}
```

...which can result in odd behaviour if you overload the variable x (see Hoisting http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).

Returning to your question, the call to getBaB.value means you're calling for getBaB as a variable assigned an object with an attribute called 'value'.

In your code, Javascript will return the function definition (which is technically an object) as the value getBaB which doesn't have a 'value' attribute and thus *undefined*.

Note: Attempting to Parse *undefined* as an int oddly returns NaN (not undefined).

As for your function...

```
  function getBaB()
{   
      var BaB=0;
      var theForm = document.forms["prrform"];
      var basebab = theForm.elements["charbab"];
      BaB = basebab.value;
      return BaB;
}
```

`return BaB` does not return an object, though you might think it does. Returning to javascript being loosely typed;  `BaB = basebab.value;` would mean BaB is a assigned a numeric value and not an object with a 'value' attribule.

Interestingly, getBaB() could still return '*undefined*' if `theForm.elements["charbab"];` is not found and '*null*' if a value is not set in 'charbab' as it overrides BaB = 0 (loosely typed ;)).

As such I'd suggest you make sure basebab returns a logical value to ensure your code behaves reliably with a quick if statement!

Hope this helps.

GW

Comment: This does help, I really shouldn't of jumped into the deep end when learning a new language, but I suppose that's part of the fun..

Comment: I can kind of see where I'm going wrong, but how do I now "link" the array to the HTML form. Sorry for the silly questions, Java is making my brain melt :)

Comment: Brilliant. Glad to help!
So I've put together a quick example you can follow for getting results from a form (highlighting the above approach): 

http://jsfiddle.net/CGWGreen/7Yj4H/2/

Though I will suggest, as a new comer to javascript, you try JQuery. Its a very powerful framework and makes tasks like these a sinch ;)

Happy coding mate.

Comment: Hey mate, if you find this helpful could you +1 me? Cheers Tom, Chris.

Comment: Dont know if you saw this? http://jsfiddle.net/CGWGreen/7Yj4H/2/

Jsfiddle is really useful for these sorts of problems ;)

Comment: cheers Chris, that was all very helpful, helps me understand more. I have thought about JQuery, but I thought learn JavaScript first then I can use JQuery to further help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your method calling is wrong. Just call the method as methodname();

So, In your code

```
  armour_types["Heavy"] = getBaB();
```

will work i guess.

Comment: Still getting undefined with this aswell.

Answer (score 0):

First the the getBAB() must return an array. I have an example from your code as follows

```
   function BlockID() {
        var IDs = new Array();
        IDs[0] = "a";
        IDs[1] = "b";
        IDs[2] = "c";
        IDs[3] = "d";
        return IDs;
 }

  var isReady = true;
  function doSaveAs(){
    var armour_types = new Array();
    armour_types["Heavy"] = BlockID();
  }

 <body>
     <input type="button" onClick="doSaveAs();">click</input>
 </body>
```

Comment: I had it in an array first, then I changed it, I should of stuck with what felt right.